# How to get the http request to work on my browser

Tags: here-api

I am using the here-api to get a 7 day forecast for my application. When I copy and paste the code onto my browser from the Here documentation using my app-code and app-id, it says that my app-id and app-code are invalid. I am wondering why this is happening since i have an account with Here and am using the code they provided.

I have already tried switching them.

```
https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json
?app_id={xxxxxx}
&app_code={xxxxxx}
&product=forecast_7days_simple
&latitude=41.83
&longitude=-87.68
```

When i enter this request i expected json in return but instead get a page that says my code is invalid. I am using safari but have tried chrome and i still get the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to remove the curly brackets around the credentials, and to remove newlines (if any) that were added in the documentation for readability.

If you do have valid credentials, the following request should work:

```
https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy&product=forecast_7days_simple&latitude=41.83&longitude=-87.68
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the query like below. For any query you can use the swagger [here](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/auto_weather/weather-observation-lat-long) . And, from the "view code" button you can download either the curl or the jQuery snippet.

```
 curl \
  -X GET \
  -H 'Content-Type: *' \
  --get 'https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json' \
    --data-urlencode 'product=forecast_7days_simple' \
    --data-urlencode 'latitude=52.516' \
    --data-urlencode 'longitude=13.389' \
    --data-urlencode 'oneobservation=true' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}'
```